# grep 3rd keyword from a string seperated by '-'

Tags: grep, cut

My hostname details are as below after showing command of    `hostname` in linux

```
my-host-test-db-10001.dns.biz.xyz.com
my-host-test2-db-10002.dns.biz.xyz.com
my-host-test3-db-10003.dns.biz.xyz.com
```

I want to fetch the 3rd string from these above (test/test2/test3). how can I achieve it?

Comment: `hostname | cut -d '-' -f3`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the simpler solution using `cut`, you can use more flexible `grep`:

```
hostname | grep -Po '^[^-]+-[^-]+-\K[^-]+'
```

For example:

```
grep -Po '^[^-]+-[^-]+-\K[^-]+' <<< 'my-host-test2-db-10002.dns.biz.xyz.com'
```

Output:

```
test2
```

Here, GNU [`grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) uses the following options:
`-P` : Use Perl regexes.
`-o` : Print the matches only (1 match per line), not the entire lines.

`\K` : Cause the regex engine to "keep" everything it had matched prior to the `\K` and not include it in the match. Specifically, ignore the preceding part of the regex when printing the match.

**SEE ALSO:**
[perlre - Perl regular expressions](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre)